# Looping through the Teams having users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched through the site and could not find exactly what I am looking for.

I was working on a quick small rails sample app in which I have `Teams` which have_many `Users` . Each users has_many records of steps and each step contains step counts and attached screenshot.

I want to display top 5 groups with highest step counts (combined steps of all users in a group).

This is just a hobby project and may be possible that it does not follow the right way, but the looping did not feel right to me, so just wanted to put it out there and see if there is a better way.

This is what I have done.

```
    /app/controllers/concerns/application_helper.rb

    module ApplicationHelper
    def topfiveteams
        @topfiveteamswithcount
        @totalcount = 0
        @all_teamshash = {}
        Team.all.each do |team|   ---> Loop 1
                teamcount = 0
                team.users.each do |user|  ---> Loop 2
                    userstepcount = 0
                    user.steps.each do |step|  ---> Loop 3
                        userstepcount += step.stepcount
                    end
                teamcount += userstepcount
                end
                @all_teamshash[team.teamname] = teamcount
        end

        h = @all_teamshash.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.reverse.to_h
        @topfiveteamswithcount = h.first(5).to_h

    end
end
```

Is there a cleaner way in RoR ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Team.joins(users: :steps).group(:id).order('SUM(stepcount) DESC').limit(5)`

If you want just the team id and stepcount sum then finish with `pluck('teams.id, SUM(stepcount)')`

This will separate out all `steps` into groups based on their team.  You then order the groups by the sum of the `stepcount` descending.  You can then grab the top 5 results to get the 5 teams with the highest overall stepcount.

I'm pretty sure Rails is smart enough to parse `group(:id)` correctly, but if you get an 'ambiguous column name' error then update it to `group('teams.id')`.

Comment: :O 
   Works perfectly. Many Thanks to you.

Only change was I think it should be Team.joins instead of Team.join

Comment: Edited the `joins` typo. Glad to hear everything worked!